# How to customize CSS with django-bootstrap3

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-bootstrap3

Im working on a project in Django that I installed Django-bootstrap3 on. It seems to have installed successfully and is generally working...but I'm not sure how to customize the css with this setup. Can anyone help?

Comment: tell us why you want django-bootstrap, maybe their is other approach

Comment: What do you want to customise?

Comment: You need to be more specific: See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own css using a css file in the static directory, the catch is that you need to place your css link tag under the bootstrap css link tag. Any css you add to your file will override most of the bootstrap styling.